# Map Cmd+Shift+[ in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

How can I map Cmd+Shift+[ and Cmd+Shift+] to cycle left and right between tabs. I just can't handle gt and gT for tab navigation, so many typos and confusion for me.

Comment: What did you try? Did you try mapping Cmd+{ and Cmd+} ?  I do not have a Mac to see whether this works.

Comment: I did that exactly and it still didn't work. <D-{> and <D-}> as well as <D-S-{> and <D-S-}>

Comment: What exact commands? And are you using the macvim gui or Vim within a terminal window?

Comment: I'm using vim within the terminal "VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4" I used a whole bunch of commands in my .vimrc nnoremap <D-S-]> :tabnext<CR> and all other variations such as , <D-S-}> , <D-S>}, <D-S>]

Comment: You can't map the command key in terminal vim, only in MacVim's GUI. You can try to add mappings directly to your terminal emulator, though. I suggest keeping up with `gt` and `gT`, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310077/use-cmd-mappings-in-console-vim. Please see my answer there; although it hasn't been accepted as correct, I think it might help you.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because I use ITerm2, and ITerm2 uses the same keybinding for navigating between its own tabs. I tried to change ITerm2's own bindings but I got lost and couldn't do that. I ended maping Vim's tab navigation to <Leader>h and <Leader>l